# Creating button to clear all layers from data frame using ArcObjects and VB.NET?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, vb.net

I'm trying to create a button using VB.NET and ArcGIS 10 to clear the layers of my data frame.

I know how to add layers, but how do I delete/clear them?

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to cast the [Map](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000s13000000) to [IMapLayers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000008zs000000) and call the [IMapLayers.ClearLayers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000900000000) method which:

> Removes all layers from the map.

Comment: How can I call IMapLayers.ClearLayers?
Thank you

Comment: Perhaps at this point it would help you to start with some high-level ArcObjects documentation on your own. The [overview for esriCarto library](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/#/Overview/001200000t32000000/) contains lots of information that will be beneficial in your case.

Comment: Also the [Working with the map](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Working_with_the_map/000100000018000000/) article could help you.

Comment: Thank you again. I'll try to understand, but is my second day with this I'm lost.

Comment: Finally I find this way:
'code'
MxDoc = My.ArcMap.Document
Map = MxDoc.FocusMap
While Map.LayerCount > 0
  Layer = Map.Layer(0)
   Map.DeleteLayer(Layer)
End While

Comment: Thank for all. Now I'm understanding better the ArcObjects :D

Comment: Great, you can learn a lot by browsing the documentation. Note you can also call `DirectCast(Map, IMapLayers).ClearLayers()` in VB.NET, where `Map` is an IMap variable. C# equivalent is `((IMapLayers)Map).ClearLayers();`.